# Was the Land's moon only visible at night?

Tags: thomas-covenant

Something that sits in the back of my mind is that the moon of the Land was only out at night.

Is that true?

It has been years since I've read the books.  The scene I recall is that Thomas is in pain when the green moon is in the sky and his boots were on the ground.  I believe it was always after (or exactly at) sunset that he would be hit with the pain.

Having the moon sync'd in that manner seemed odd to me when younger, and has only gotten odder when I think back on it.

Am I remembering it correctly?

Comment: Donaldson didn't understand basic astronomy?

Comment: There's no mention of the moon being visible during the day in the first two trilogies. It always rises after sunset

Comment: Right. I've been through all of the main series books. There's always a mention of inky black skies, visible stars and a sunset before any mention of the moon. It always seems to set prior to sunrise.

Comment: I was in elementary school when one day I noticed the Moon in the blue sky.  It seems a little hard to believe that Donaldson could be old enough to write novels and never have noticed the Moon in the daytime.  I think that if the green moon orbited the planet in less than one day it might rise and set and rise again and set again two or more times during a day.  And if the green moon was faint enough it might only be visible whenit was hight in the sky in the middle of the night.  So possibly a question about the astronomical possibility of such a situation is needed.

Comment: Pain at sunset while his boots are on the ground sounds like the Sunbane(?), which is something from the second trilogy, not the first.  There might have been something in the third set of books involving being open to attacks by evil when standing on bare rock?  I forget.

Comment: @LAK   It's possible, but I think it was in the first trilogy, possibly even the first book.   His non-Land boots were allowing him to be tracked and caused pain.  Once he took them off, he was fine.

Comment: Why would we think the Land is anything like our universe?  Is the world even round?  Are the stars lights on a crystal dome? (Remember the stars winking out one by one, leading up to the Last Dark?)   I think the craziest thing about the Covenent saga is that the Land has people that can cross-breed with humans from our world.

Comment: @GEdgar I guess an additional question would be if the moon is always full.  If it is always full, then it would always be opposite of the sun and would be rising everyday while the sun was setting.   I think I recall phases though.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson - The moon goes through distinct phases